# JavaScript. Как найти элемент по ID внутри элемента которого ещё нет в document?

Tags: javascript

Например: элемент a создан с помощью произвольной функции, внутри нового элемента есть несколько элементов которые имеют свой id

Вот эта команда работать не будет: (функция getElementById() есть только в элементе document)

```
a.getElementById('page_right').appendChild(b);
```

Comment: Поскольку `id` на странице должен быть уникальным, то вы вполне можете вызывать `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.querySelector('#page_right').appendChild(b);
```